# Find a triangle whose three sides and area and perimeter are all square numbers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find a triangle whose three sidelengths and area and perimeter are all square numbers.

Taking $a^2,b^2,c^2$ be the sidelengths of the triangle,then we need to find positive integer solutions to this equation:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=x^2,\\
x^2(x^2-2a^2)(x^2-2b^2)(x^2-2c^2)=y^4.$$

Let $x=1$ then we need to find positive rational solutions to this equation:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=1,\\
(1^2-2a^2)(1^2-2b^2)(1^2-2c^2)=y^4.$$

Comment: If you have $x=1$, then $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ has integer solution only for $a=1$ and $b=c=0$ (or any permutation). But these do not form a triangle.

Comment: @Andrei If $x=1$ then we only need to find rational solutions.